# Always app Java end with "Exit 143" Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, exit

I have an application in java, which is permanently pulled. Execute it as follows:

```
nohup ant> log.txt &
```

The problem is that last indefinitely, the application quits and get a message "Exit 143".

Comment: We're not clairvoyant. Provide more info if you want answers. I'd say the problem lies in your Java app.

Comment: I disagree with this being marked as duplicate. I was searching for what exit code 143 means, and this question and the accepted answer explained it perfectly. The question that this supposedly duplicates does NOT answer the problem I was searching for.

Answer (score 39):

Exit code 143 corresponds to `SIGTERM`, which is the signal sent by default when you run `kill <pid>`.  Is it possible that another process or user is killing the application?  Without more information it's difficult to suggest anything else.

Comment: I do not think that is another user, maybe another process?
I did this to try and protect myself from SIGTERM, how do you see?

Comment: This can happen in a Docker environment when the container decides that something is using too much memory and kills the largest process.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar issue while using nodejs, and it turned out that it was actually my app and my code that was killing it.

I had code like this (ok, i don't have function names like that, but you get the point):

```
kill_anything_that_is_still_running_from_previous_execution()
start_a_lot_of_stuff()
```

The problem was that `kill_anything_that_is_still_running_from_previous_execution` was async and returned immediately and (due to bad "luck") the actual killing part always ended up happening only after `start_a_lot_of_stuff` finished running, which is obviously not very great. #spawncamping

Oh, and **in Java** `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash -c \"killall whatever\"")` is "async" if you don't wait for it to exit.