# Linux: get the exit code from the kill command

Tags: linux, kill, exit-code, sigterm

If I send a `SIGTERM` signal to a process using the `kill` command, I expect an exit code, but I always get 0 (zero) when running the below command after killing a process:

```
echo $?
```

According to the answer in this post, I should get 143 when sending a `SIGTERM` to a process: [Always app Java end with "Exit 143" Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192364/always-app-java-end-with-exit-143-ubuntu)

But I don´t get that exit code. Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The exit code you get is for the `kill` command itself. 0 means it succeeded, i.e. the other process got the signal you sent it. `kill` just doesn't report the exit status for the process, since it can't even be sure the other process exited as a result of the signal it sent.

Comment: Ah, ok! Is there any way to check the exit code of the process that is beeing killed?

Comment: @Rox: I believe only the parent process has direct access to the exit status, so not directly.

Comment: It is possible to check the exit code of the process being killed.  Use ptrace to attach to it before you send the signal.  (This is probably more trouble than it is worth!)  Alternatively, have the parent of the killed process report its exit status.

Comment: Any reference for the exit code of the `kill` command itself?

Comment: @OhadSchneider: `$ man kill`, which tells us: 0 = success, 1 = failure, 64 partial success (when more than one process specified).

Comment: @Sathors thanks. Most man pages don't mention it, but it seems at least some do (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html). Lord knows if the latter applies to all the systems that don't have it mentioned in their man. One day I'll understand why the same command has 19 different man pages (I'm guessing they have to do with different distros but still)...