# Eclipse Kepler fails to start Tomcat 7

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I'm using Eclipse Kepler and Tomcat 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. When Tomcat starts it after 45 seconds it says

```
Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.
```

I increased the timeout, reinstalled Eclipse and Tomcat but still the problem is not solved.

In debug mode I get this error.

```
<terminated, exit value: 143>/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (May 26, 2014, 12:26:09 PM)
```

My console says:

```
May 26, 2014 12:26:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
May 26, 2014 12:26:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 26, 2014 12:26:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 26, 2014 12:26:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 995 ms
May 26, 2014 12:26:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 26, 2014 12:26:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
May 26, 2014 12:26:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 26, 2014 12:26:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 26, 2014 12:26:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 804 ms
```

Comment: Click on Servers (for Tomcat Server) in the views in Kepler. Select Timeouts in the overview in Servers and set to the value you require.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845219/change-tomcat-servers-timeout-in-eclipse

Comment: I did that. But still not working :(

Comment: some process of yours is sending kill signal i.e code 143.. Can you please check? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192364/always-app-java-end-with-exit-143-ubuntu

Comment: Sorry. I dont know how to do it. But some pointers are available here. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/738b7897-cd38-4f24-9f05-48dd69116837/entry/debugging_java_application_crashes_without_any_logs4?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Add server runtime at starting of creation of anything in your eclipse environment 
add specified installed tomcat library and jdk location and it will works